# Counting the number of rows from db with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm making some commentary system, and I'm having a problem. I have made it look like a mail system, so that the messages can be moved from inbox into two separate bins- trash and important, and to count the number of messages they contain and that's the problem.

When I send my items from inbox to the trash bin, they go there. And when I want to move important information from the inbox to the important information bin, not only do the marked important messages go there, but also, for some reason unknown to me, the latest messages that I had already sent to the trash bin get moved to the important bin as well. I do not know why it is happening. Thanks in advance

in order to count how many messages there are, and how to transfer them, I used ajax. The transfer of messages had been working normally until I decided that I wanted the messages to be counted. In order for it to show me how many messages there were, without needing to refresh the page, I put in setinterval.

Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn_delete').click(function(){
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want remove to trash ?")){
            var id = [];

            $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
                id[i] = $(this).val();
            });

            if(id.length === 0){ //tell you if the array is empty
                alert("Please Select atleast one checkbox");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url:'private/email/trash.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{id:id},
                    success:function(){
                        for(var i=0; i<id.length; i++){
                            $('tr#'+id[i]+'').css('background-color', '#ccc');
                            $('tr#'+id[i]+'').fadeOut('slow');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn_important').click(function(){
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want remove to important ?")){

            var id = [];

            $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
                id[i] = $(this).val();
            });

            if(id.length === 0){ //tell you if the array is empty
                alert("Please Select atleast one checkbox");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url:'private/email/important.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{id:id},
                    success:function() {
                        for(var i=0; i<id.length; i++) {
                            $('tr#'+id[i]+'').css('background-color', '#ccc');
                            $('tr#'+id[i]+'').fadeOut('slow');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});

setInterval(function () {
    $('#show').load('private/email/count_inbox.php');
    $('#inbox').load('private/email/count_inbox.php');
    $('#important').load('private/email/count_important.php');
    $('#trash').load('private/email/count_trash.php');
}, 5000);
</script>
```

Count trash

```
<?php
require_once("../../private/initialize.php"); 
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM comments WHERE deleted = 0";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$com = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $com['total'];

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Update Important

```
<?php
require_once("../../private/initialize.php");

if(isset($_POST["id"])) {
    foreach($_POST["id"] as $id) {
        $query = "UPDATE comments SET deleted = 2 WHERE comment_id = '".$id."'";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    }
}
mysqli_free_result($query);
mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

Count important

```
<?php
require_once("../../private/initialize.php"); 
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM comments WHERE deleted = 2";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$com = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $com['total'];

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Was it smart of me to do that in the first place? Should I have not put in setinterval?

This is how it looks

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this problem? Sorry for uploading a longer question.

Comment: Why are your `intervals` so short? **100** milliseconds - 1/10th of a second seems a bit much... Also why not place all those `load()` functions into one `interval` since you are using the same times for each one...

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I have already tried to implement such changes before, and it doesn't help :(  The problem remains.

Comment: you should consider using web sockets http://socketo.me/

Comment: What does your PHP look like for moving the files? What does your PHP look like for the 4 files mentioned in your original post? And you should try what @NewToJS suggested, place everything in one `setInterval`, sure won't fix your issue but it's much neater.

Comment: So basically it's "When you mark something for important, it's removed from the trash and goes into the important file and that's not what you want is that correct?" What is `$_POST['id']'`? What does your form look like?

Comment: It looks like you're doing way too many ajax calls to get the counts. Either group the counts into a single call, or just increment the counts without ajax(plenty of sites do it that way).

Comment: Also, your 'var id' is probably "catching" the IDs you delete, and sending them with the "important" ajax as well. Add a few 'console.log(id)' rows to be able to track what's going on.

Comment: PLEASE don't use POST variables directly in MySQL queries. Read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) about PDO and start using it. This is vulnerable to SQL injections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you are not clearing the selection of items after moving them either to trash or important.

`fadeOut` method will only hide them from the page but you are neither unchecking them nor deleting them on AJAX success. Thus, you are collecting their ids again on `btn.click()`.

Try removing the items:

```js
$('tr#'+id[i]+'').fadeOut('slow').remove();
```

Comment: foxdie, thank you for editing the answer with markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Guys thank you all a lot. The problem was that when fadeOut was done, the checkboxes remained checked, but weren't seen. It was enough for me on $('tr#'+id[i]+'').fadeOut('slow')  to add .remove();  and the problem was gone.
Again, thank you all so much, sincerely.